# Adding Strings with Choppers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get an output that looks like this:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> 1234
>
> 5678
>
> 9012
>
> 3456
>
> 789

The first line being a String of numbers (line) and the last line being all of the numbers printed out in increments of 4 (breaker). Here is the code I got so far (I am using two different files or programs or whatever because of my teacher).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class LineBreaker {

    private String line;
    private int breaker;

    public LineBreaker() {
        this("", 0);
    }

    public LineBreaker(String s, int b) {
        line=s;
        breaker=b;
    }

    public void setLineBreaker(String s, int b) {
        line=s;
        breaker=b;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    public String getLineBreaker() {
        String box = "";
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(line);
        while (chopper.hasNext()){
            for (int i=0;i<breaker;i++){
                box+=chopper.next();
            }
            box=box+"\n";
        }
        return box;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getLine()+"\n"+getLineBreaker()+"\n";
    }
}
```

(the next one is in the separate file)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class LineBreakerRunner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LineBreaker test = new LineBreaker("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9",4);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Here is the error message that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at lab12_scanner_chopper.LineBreaker.getLineBreaker(LineBreaker.java:41)
    at lab12_scanner_chopper.LineBreaker.toString(LineBreaker.java:49)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at lab12_scanner_chopper.LineBreakerRunner.main(LineBreakerRunner.java:16)
C:\Users\Harrison\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The error is pointing to the line in `LingBreaker` where it says `box+=chopper.next();` So I think that the problem is me adding the chopped bit to a string. But I don't really get why that is a problem. I need to use a Scanner/chopper to get credit.

Comment: for your information, java.lang is imported by default, you do not need to explicitly import it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a lot of code for what appears to be a simple problem. I would print the `String`. I would use a regular expression to remove all of the white space. Then I would iterate the input and increment by 4 characters at a time. Like,

```
String s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", s1 = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
int len = s1.length();
System.out.println(s);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
    if (i + 1 < len) {
        System.out.print(s1.charAt(i + 1));
    }
    if (i + 2 < len) {
        System.out.print(s1.charAt(i + 2));
    }
    if (i + 3 < len) {
        System.out.print(s1.charAt(i + 3));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1234
5678
9012
3456
789
```

And if you need same with a `Scanner` then (for the same result), do something like

```
String s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
System.out.println(s);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print(sc.nextInt());
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print(sc.nextInt());
    }
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print(sc.nextInt());
    }
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print(sc.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have to use a chopper to get the output.

Comment: @Steven.Cramer Do you mean a `Scanner`? If so, you should edit your question to include that little detail.

Comment: I think I mean Scanner, I did edit the question after I realized I forgot to mention it. I'll change it to say Scanner/Chopper. (I don't really know the terminology very well)